# command 'cmake.build' not found

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code for C++ development with Cmake. Normally, the build command, F7, runs uses cmake to build the project, but now when I run the build task, I get a warning `command 'cmake.build' not found` and nothing happens after that, so the project never gets built.

I am running on Ubuntu nad have the CMake dependency and Cmake tools, as well as the command line cmake, ccmake, and cmake-gui already installed. I have already uninstalled and reinstalled with an apt-get purge code and I reinstalled my $HOME/.vscode extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the github issue: [#163](https://github.com/vector-of-bool/vscode-cmake-tools/issues/163)

It appears that there is a bug with CMake Server. A workaround is to go into the Visual Studio Code `Settings.json` and set `cmake.useCMakeServer` to `false`. This worked for me and appears to have worked for others having a similar problem.